# What would be the right way to say "I haven't drove this red car in a year"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am thinking of either
Nōn in annō hanc raedam rubrmam gubernō.
or..
Nōn annum hanc raedam rubram gobernō.

I want to say something in the lines of "It's been a year since I last drove this red car".

To be fair, I am a beginner and I still struggle with cases lol. Hope anyone can help, and thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to use *cum* with the indicative:

> Unus annus est, cum raedam non guberno.
> *It is now one year that I have not driven the car.*

Compare Cic. Phil. 12,24:

> Vicesimus annus est, cum omnes scelerati me unum petunt.
> For twenty years all the evildoers have assailed me alone.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Unless I'm getting mixed up, "unus" is a cardinal number, "vicesimus" is ordinal. Can either be used in this construction?

Comment: @Kingshorsey oops, you're right, that Cicero quote is not the best example. But see e.g. ad fam. 15,14: *multi enim anni sunt, cum ille in aere meo est et a me diligitur*. Both are possible, but now I'm wondering if *vicesimus annus est* does not mean "it has been **nineteen** years"? And in this case we would have to say *secundus annus est*, which seems a little weird to me; for one year, I like the cardinal-number version better.